# Gamma distribution and hyperparameters

Tags: self-study, posterior, gamma-distribution, hyperparameter, conjugate-prior

The formula for mean and variance of a gamma distribution is given by a/b and a/b^2 (hyperparameters) respectively.Are they estimates of the posterior gamma distribution?

Can prior, likelihood and posterior all 3 have gamma distribution, and can their means and variances computed using the formula above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your likelihood function is a Gamma with known shape, $a$, and the parameter of interest is the rate, $b$, then the Gamma distribution is a conjugate prior - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_continuous_distribution

The choice of a (Gamma) conjugate prior means that your posterior will also have a (Gamma) probability distribution, this is the definition of a conjugate prior.  This simple form of the posterior distribution is precisely the reason to choose such a prior.  Yes, therefore, one can have all three of prior, likelihood and posterior Gamma distributed.

In Bayesian analysis the parameters are uncertain, the data is not - i.e. we are interested in $P[parameters | data]$.

Having chosen a conjugate prior there is normally a simple formula to **update** the parameters in the posterior distribution from the prior  - see the wikipedia table examples above.

As you correctly say, any Gamma distribution is uniquely specified my its mean and variance: you can calculate these from $a$,$b$ using the formula you give, or you can use the mean and variance to estimate $a$,$b$ by reversing the equations you quote.